# document.getElementById as a variable in xhtml

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I am trying to insert some new links using ‘innerHTML’. As there may be a number of calls on the same ‘ids’ I thought it would be wise to use variables. The following does not respond beyond the alert? The process works fine if I don’t use ‘var link’ and just enter it in full. Is there an issue perhaps trying to do this with xhtml?

Thanks.

```
var newlink = '<a title="new link" href="newlink.htm">New Link</a>';
var link  = "document.getElementById('idlink')";

if( link )  { 
alert("link confirmed");
link.innerHTML = newlink;
}
```

Comment: Really dont understand this bit -> "As there may be a number of calls on the same ‘ids’ I thought it would be wise to use variables. " can you explain ?

Comment: Why is `"document.getElementById('idlink')"` a string?

Comment: @Smamatti could be a `span` or `div` or `p` etc

Comment: MansellUK - in response to your first comment - as I will be checking for the existence of "document.getElementById('idlink')" first and then calling it again to alter the innerHTML, this is at least 2 instances, there could be more. Am I wrong to assume that using a variable will involve less processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning a string to the variable. Just because the contents of the string looks like code that could be run doesn't mean that it actually runs. It's just a string.

Call the method and assign the result to the variable:

```
var link = document.getElementById('idlink');
```

Comment: Thanks Guffa, please see my comment to ManseUK.

Comment: @martin: Do you run the script in the onload event, or in a script tag below the element that you try to find? Otherwise the element doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Guffa, I was assigning the 'var link' in the head of the document, presumably this was the problem. If I assign it further down the page after the element it works.

Answer (score 4):

```
var link  = "document.getElementById('idlink')";
```

should be

```
var link  = document.getElementById('idlink');
```

Comment: Thanks ManseUK, I started without the quotes, but then I'm not even getting as far as a response to the alert?

Comment: @martin Add in your HMTL to your question and i will take another look